# A simple optimization problem of reciprocal function

Tags: calculus, optimization

Can someone tell me the answer to this question?
I cannot seem to figure it out

The function $y=\frac{2}{x}$ is decreasing in??

a.$(0,\infty)$

b.$(-\infty,0)$

c.$(0,2)$

d,$(-\infty,\infty)$

I think b is the correct option but a lot of other people say it's wrong.

Please provide a detailed solution.

Comment: Is this a home work question? if so add the homeework tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$y = \frac{2}{x}$$
So
$$y' = -\frac{2}{x^2}$$
A function is decreasing in the interval $[a, b]$ when $y' < 0$ in the inteval $[a, b]$. We notice that $y' < 0$ for all $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$ except when $x = 0$.

Therefore, $y$ is decreasing on the interval $(-\infty, 0) \bigcup (0, \infty)$, which isn't any of the answers you posted.

Answer (score 1):

The function $y=\frac{2}{x}$ has a derivative of $y'=-\frac{2}{x^2}$ which is negative everywhere except for $x=0$